# Designer redirects to code

Tags: visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio, rightclicking a .xaml file and choosing 'View Designer' keeps showing me the XAML instead of the GUI. I can't view the Designer whatever I do. I'm running Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. I've tried looking at other answers but it seems their problem is they don't have a Designer 'button'. It's there alright, but it just keeps showing me the code instead of the view.

I think I might know the cause of the problem:
A week ago my second harddisk containing Visual Studio 2013 decided to die.
Yesterday I bought a new harddisk and swapped it out with the old one. Now, both harddisks have one thing in common other capacity. They both have the same drive letter.

When installing Visual Studio again today, Windows somehow thought it was still installed, so the Setup didn't really do much. I instead retorted to repairing the install. Now I could launch Visual Studio, but then I had this problem.
Is there a way to completely obliterate/harddelete Visual Studio? Upon uninstall and reinstall, during reinstall it STILL thinks the install is still there, so you always have to run a repair. It's bugged.

Any ideas?

Comment: "choosing 'View Designer' keeps showing me the XAML instead of the GUI." - The XAML *is* the GUI, in some ways. Have you tried Right Click on XAML -> View Designer? Or Shift+F7?

Comment: Shift+F7 shows me the code, like View Designer does.

Comment: On the Top Left (or Bottom Left) of the XAML window, you should see two tabs, one called 'XAML', and the other 'Design'. Click on 'Design', does that work?

Comment: Can't see the buttons actually, but I don't think it would work anyway. I think it would be easier to just uninstall everything in a permanent sense. I can't seem to remove every trace of Visual Studio no matter what I do.

Comment: There should be a small box that has a separator which shows that current tab you are on is a xaml tab and you can use that to switch your view to design tab.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys but something was seriously wrong with Visual Studio. Upon uninstall, the entire program was still in the folder. Upon reinstall, it kept wanting to install to the same directory. I'll switch to another version of VS. Thank you though

Comment: It isn't very clear why you did not lose the registry when the drive failed.  Having a mismatch between the registry and the actual files on disk is rather bad and guaranteed to cause trouble.   Best bet is to run setup.exe /uninstall /force